# copy/paste clipboard periodically corrupted after reload vmware guest system

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I have annyoning and difficult reproducible bug with my vmware workstation systems (v11.1.0.58002,(same behavior for any lower version), Win7_64bit host).
After i reload any of guest sustems, a clipboard from this system stop working, and starts working only if i do:

1. Restart vmware.exe on my host system. (Bad, when i use more than one system)
2. Restart both vmtoolsd.exe process in guest system:

> ```
> taskkill /F /IM vmtoolsd.exe
> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\vmtoolsd.exe" -n vmusr
> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\vmtoolsd.exe"
> ```

This solutions does not work:

3. Change *.vmx:

> ```
> isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
> isolation.tools.copy.disable = "FALSE"
> isolation.tools.dnd.disable = "FALSE"
> isolation.tools.paste.disable = "FALSE"
> ```

Any idea how to fix this problem without reboot/restart process?